# Ionic app and Access-Control-Allow-Headers on Nginx

Tags: ionic-framework, cors

I have a Ionic app that use a API hosted on a site and with `ionic serve` and chrome cors plugin I'm able to use the app.
When I try it on the ios emulator with `ionic cordova run ios` the app starts but no content is displayed.

Using safari as debugger I have found the issue:

> Failed to load resource: Request header field User-Agent is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

The problem is that in my site, which is a Wordpress installation, I have this code:

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, User-Agent, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, X-CLIENT-ID, X-CLIENT-SECRET');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

and as you can see the `User-Agent` is allowed in headers.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the service proxy configuration for Ionic instead of randomly granting these permissions.

Add this to your ionic.config.json:

```
...
proxies: [
    {path: "/path/to/resource", proxyUrl: "http://myserver.com/path/to/resource"}
]
...
```

See this link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuring.html

I usually put these URLs in a config file. I maintain two files for development and production use. Once you deploy the app to a device you can use the regular URLs again (production config file) because cross origin requests aren't prohibited within embedded WebViews.